# Why do only two of the three pipes write between the processes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, fork

I'm currently working on a project where I have to use `os.pipe()` and `os.fork()` in Python.
I have alread set up the processes with the fork function so I (should) have one parent with two children, from which one has a children on it's own.

In the first version of my code, it seems that only two of three pipes were read:

```
import os
import random



pid=os.fork()

r, w = os.pipe()
r2, w2 = os.pipe()
r3, w3 = os.pipe()

if pid != 0:

    pid2=os.fork()
    
    if pid2 != 0:

        print("Parent")
        os.close(r)
        os.close(r2)
        pipe1 = b"Pipe1 read"
        pipe2 = b"Pipe2 read"
        os.write(w, pipe1)
        os.write(w2, pipe2)
        
    if pid2 == 0:
        print("Child2")
        os.close(w2)
        r2 = os.fdopen(r2)
        print(r2.read())
        
        
        
if pid == 0:
    pid3=os.fork()
    os.close(w)
    r = os.fdopen(r)
    print(r.read())
    if pid3 != 0:
        
        os.close(r3)
        print("Child1")
        pipe3 = b"Pipe3 read"
        os.write(w3, pipe3)
        
        
    if pid3 == 0:
        print("Child from Child")
        os.close(w3)
        r3 = os.fdopen(r3)
        print(r3.read())
```

Output:

```
Parent
Child2
Child1
Child from Child
Pipe2 read
Pipe3 read
```

The other version would be:

```
import os
import random



pid = os.fork()

r, w = os.pipe()
r2, w2 = os.pipe()
r3, w3 = os.pipe()

if pid != 0:

    pid2 = os.fork()

    if pid2 != 0:
        print("Parent")
        os.close(r)
        os.close(r2)
        pipe1 = b"Pipe1 read"
        pipe2 = b"Pipe2 read"
        os.write(w, pipe1)
        os.write(w2, pipe2)

    if pid2 == 0:
        print("Child2")
        os.close(w2)
        r2 = os.fdopen(r2)
        print(r2.read())

#Only changed the order here!
if pid == 0:
    pid3 = os.fork()
    if pid3 != 0:
        os.close(w)
        r = os.fdopen(r)
        print(r.read())
        os.close(r3)
        print("Child1")
        pipe3 = b"Pipe3 read"
        os.write(w3, pipe3)

    if pid3 == 0:
        print("Child from Child")
        os.close(w3)
        r3 = os.fdopen(r3)
        print(r3.read())
```

Output:

```
Parent
Child2
Child from Child
Pipe2 read
```

In the second version the third pipe also seems to disappear or break Child1.
Could someone please explain me where my problem is and how I connect a pipe correctly from Parent to Child1 (and from Partent to Child2 at the same time).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first one, you should setup the first pipe `r, w = os.pipe()` before you fork. Otherwise you end up with Child1 reading from a different pipe than what Parent is writing to.

In the second one, you need to close the all the extra pipes in the children with (pid==0). That is: Move `r3, w3 = os.pipe()` to after `pid==0`, move `os.close(w)` to before `pid3!=0`, and add `os.close(r)` in `pid3==0`. Then everything should work properly.

Fixed version:

```py
import os
import random



r, w = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()

r2, w2 = os.pipe()

if pid != 0:

    pid2 = os.fork()

    if pid2 != 0:
        print("Parent")
        os.close(r)
        os.close(r2)
        pipe1 = b"Pipe1 read"
        pipe2 = b"Pipe2 read"
        os.write(w, pipe1)
        os.write(w2, pipe2)

    if pid2 == 0:
        print("Child2")
        os.close(w2)
        r2 = os.fdopen(r2)
        print(r2.read())

#Only changed the order here!
if pid == 0:
    r3, w3 = os.pipe()
    os.close(w)
    pid3 = os.fork()
    if pid3 != 0:
        r = os.fdopen(r)
        print(r.read())
        os.close(r3)
        print("Child1")
        pipe3 = b"Pipe3 read"
        os.write(w3, pipe3)

    if pid3 == 0:
        os.close(r)
        print("Child from Child")
        os.close(w3)
        r3 = os.fdopen(r3)
        print(r3.read())
```

Comment: Thank you really much. Works fine now.
I got a bit confused with where I should create the pipes so they can communicate with the right processes, but now it's clear. Thanks!